Decimals in Geometry Nodes

Hi everyone, I need some help, look, I've been looking for how I can display two decimal places or maybe three in the node information to keep the information on the screen and not have to always open it to remember the number, in the configuration I put 70.52º but the node only shows the first decimal 70.5º, thanks!

I don't think it's possible, according to a 2022 post on blenderartist.
